# What is the 'Add' node and where is it?

Tags: node-editor

I was watching a tutorial on making glass, and it included this node, however I wasn't able to find it anywhere, is it an add-on or am I just missing it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a "Math" node;

[image]

It takes on the name of the operation you are applying to the inputs;

[image]

[image]

My most frequent use of it is to multiply input to increase or decrease the strength of Mix Shader nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Just search 'math' or

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Go into *Converter*
3. Select *Math* node

Comment: Consider accepting other answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172391/15543

Comment: yes ! when I was typing the solution, I did not notice the other answer!